# How can I set or clear the proxy server used by a Windows Mobile device?

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, proxy

I want to programatically configure the proxy settings for the wifi network on my Windows Mobile phone.  Does anybody know how to do that using the .net compact framework?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [DMProcessConfigXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158518.aspx) api call to configure up a lot of the settings on the device. I think you might want to use the [CM_ProxyEntries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb737453%28v=MSDN.10%29.aspx) configuration service provider, which allows you to create and delete proxy settings. One approach may be to set up the wifi proxy manually, then use DMProcessConfigXML to query the settings, which will give you the xml you can use (with a few tweaks) to configure it up programmatically.

Comment: I'm looking into this.  It seems to be what I'm looking for.  Will keep you updated as the project progresses.  I don't get much time to work on it though, so it might take a while.